# appending an image with text to EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am facing a problem here. I want to add images along with text in an EditText, but after lots of searching I reached a conclusion that I couldnt add images with text. **UPTILL** I got this piece of code that is supposed to be adding images to text in editText.

```
ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_emo_angry));
            SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
            builder.append(input.getText());
            String imgId = "[img=1]"; 
            int selStart = input.getSelectionStart();

            // current selection is replaceв with imageId
            builder.replace(input.getSelectionStart(), input.getSelectionEnd(), imgId);
            builder.setSpan(imageSpan, selStart, selStart + imgId.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            input.setText(builder);
```

but when I tried it, it didn't work also. so Is there a way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: is it showing any error if it showing please post your logcat error.

Answer (score 1):

**I MANAGED TO FIX IT**

Here is how I fixed the problem:

```
ImageGetter imageGetter = new ImageGetter() {
                    @Override
                    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
                        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(
                                cslistemoji.images[x]);
                        d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
                        return d;
                    } 

                };

                cs = Html.fromHtml(
                        "<img src='"
                                + getResources()
                                        .getDrawable(cslistemoji.images[pos])
                                + "'/>", imageGetter, null);
                System.out.println("cs is:- " + cs);
                String s = status.getText().toString();
                status.append(cs);
```

Comment: How can you pull an image from the internet? ie. http://localhost:3000/image/2/2.jpg that can then be placed within you application

Comment: Exactly how to show images from other resources like url or sdcard?